# how to create dictionary in with multiple values?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary in C# with one key and multiple keys associated with the key.I also want to retrieve the values based on the key.I found on internet people suggested to use a tuple but couldn't find a proper example. How to use it and retrieve the data?

Goal:  I want to parse a JSON response and store response in key pair form.

Comment: [Google results for "Tuple example"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tuple+example&oq=tuple+example&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2073j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) - are you really after a dictionary dictionary?

Comment: No actually I want to parse a json response and store response in key pair form.I dont know what data stucture will be good for it.

Comment: JSON.Net will take care of parsing JSON. Unless it is homework please don't invent square wheel.

Comment: I've removed thank you notes from you post and inlined your JSON comment. Feel free to update your post if my edit changed meaning (I hope it did not).

Comment: Thanks for that,actually i know how to parse the json response but ya I am not clear on how to store in key with multiple values form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking for would look something like this

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, string>>
```

But what you should do is create an class to replace that Tuple

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can define your Dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<int, Person> bar = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
```

Then you could retrieve values like this

```
var firstName = bar[1].FirstName  //1 is the key of the dictionary item
```

Comment: can you tell me how to retrieve the data?

Comment: updated to show retrieving a value from the dictionary

Comment: checkout [dotnetfiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/45af0g) which follows this approach.

Answer (score 7):

When I have needed to do something like this, I usually just create a custom class that can be used as the value. For example, if I wanted to store a dictionary with a digit as the key and a name, address, and phone number as the value, I'd create a Person class to contain the name, address, and phone number.

```
Dictionary<int, Person> = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
```

Alternately you can just make the value an array or List.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you want:

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>> = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

But I think it fit your need.